# Resetting operation between events

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like:

```
//*Global variables*
var numStr="";
var symbol="";
var numero=[];
var total=0;
var totaldisplay="";
//...
//*Event*
$("button").click(function(){
   var key=$(this).html();
  // *if statements*
    if(/\d{1,}|\./.test(key)){
          numStr+=key;
          totalDisplay+=key;
                   }

    if(/÷|\+|-|×/.test(key)) {
          symbol=key;
          numero.push(parseFloat(numStr));
          numStr="";
          totalDisplay+=key;

          }
    if(/=/.test(key)){
         numero.push(parseFloat(numStr));
         numStr="";
         ....
         total= // *Operations*

         totalDisplay+="="+total;


}

  //....
  $("#display2").html(totalDisplay);

})
```

I think I did not word the problem properly in my first post.
It is a calculator, the user click the key and that adds up in the display of the calculator.

Example:

- The first click 2:`numStr="2" and totalDisplay="2"`.
- Second click 4:`numStr="24" and totalDisplay="24"`.
- Third click +:`symbol="+"` , `numStr converted into a type number and pushed into the array numero`,`numStr=""` and `totalDisplay="24+"`.
- Fourth click 9: `numStr=9`, `totalDisplay="24+9"`.
- Fifth click =: `numStr converted into a type number and push into the array numero`,`numStr=""`, it makes the operation and `totalDisplay="24+9=33"`
- **(Problem)** Sixth click 7: `numStr="97"`,`"totalDisplay="24+9=337"`.
  How can I start a fresh second operation  once it is over the first one. 
  So, after the fifth click that makes and display the first operation, all the variables are set to 0 or to empty string ""; and with the sixth click 
  `numStr="7"` and `totalDisplay="7"`.

Comment: That's an invalid JavaScript.

Comment: You can reset it in click `numStr = ''; total=0;` before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the variables at the beginning of the click handler.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  numStr = "";
  var key = $(this).html();
  //if statements *
  if (/\d{1,}|\./.test(key)) {
    numStr += key;
  }
  // ....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your global variables inside your click event.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this -

```
var numStr="";
var total=0;

$("button").click(function(){
   // Variable should always be defined at top of function definition.
   var key = $(this).html();

   // Early return, it's a good practise
   if(!(/\d{1,}|\./.test(key))){
       return;
   }

   numStr = key;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//*Global variables*
var numStr="";
var total=0;
//...
//*Event*
$("button").click(function(){
   var numStr = "";
   var key=$(this).html();
  // *if statements*
    if(/\d{1,}|\./.test(key)){
          numStr+=key;}
  //....
})
```